# Multiple master layouts in ruby on rails like laravel

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i'm new to ror and i would like to know if there is a way to say whick html file i would like to put the content of the partials, let me explain a little bit.

In Laravel, you can have a masterLayout for like, you main page, and a master layout for you dashboard and then extend these files to be able to make your layout with your partials. How can i do this in ROR?

For what i've studied, i couldn't find a way to do this, just a single application.html.erb file and putting view files inside of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create any number of layouts. Put them in app/views/layouts directory.

Now, you can manualy specify what layout do you want to use:

1) Controller level:

```
class DashboardController < ApplicationController
    layout 'dashboard'
end
```

2) Action level:

```
render 'view_name', layout: 'dashboard'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can you `test.html.erb` instead of `application.html.erb`

```
def test
  render 'template_name', layout: 'test'
end
```

Comment: what i'm saying is. If you create a partial inside the views folder it will be rendered to application.html.erb yield tag, right? Ok, if i want to load a different application.html.erb? am i clear now?

Answer (score 0):

Just take a look into the [Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html) of Rails at 2.2.14. It explains how Rails renders layouts. It always looks for a layout with the same name as the controller and if it doesn't find one, it uses the default `application.html.erb` layout. You can also specify a custom layout with the `.layout` method.

Just a short example extracted from the guides:

```
class PhotosController < ApplicationController
end
```

Here will Rails look for a `photos.html.erb` layout and if it doesn't find one it will use the default one.